Managing Multiple OAuth Providers in Django/DRF
Let's say I have two OAuth providers, Google and GitHub with which user can create an account in my Django application. I wrote a custom user model and a custom model for storing OAuth details (provider and user ID from provider etc.).
Let's say the user logs-in with GitHub first and creates an account. He logs out, signs-up again, but this time with Google.
Now what happens? How can I know that the user already has an account linked with GitHub? I cannot check the email because their email can be different for different platforms. I cannot use the ID of the user from OAuth provider too.
Please do not ask me to use libraries, I'm willing to learn how to implement it on my own.

In my experience, we always chose email as a unique identifier for a user when implementing OAuth because users typically try to use the same email. When this wasn't the case, we created a new profile.
Without a similar identifier, there’s no way to determine if a user is already registered. It could be a combination of the first and last name, or an email. The choice is yours.
But there are ways to handle the case without creating new profiles. You can add custom logic that asks the user, Do you already have a profile? before completing registration. If the answer is yes, this email can be added to, for example, an M2M table that links users and emails with the OAuth source. Or you can have a feature to merge profiles if a user wants to do it. But I am sure there are other ways to achieve this. This is just what comes first in my mind.
